# When should I repost a question with modification versus editing an existing one?

Tags: discussion, editing, asking-questions, deleting-posts

I now realize that I've asked the [wrong question here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/188803/what-tools-are-there-to-make-this-alien-language) and was about to edit it to ask what languages I could combine to get the desired effect, but that's a pretty different question than how to make a language, which prompted me to ask this question.

When do I edit a question, and when do I (maybe delete and) try again?

Comment: Please not that "combining" two languages is not a well-defined operation. In fact, the phrase has no immediately understandable meaning, and you would need to explain what is the intended combination process.

Answer (score 3):

Basically: if the question has no answers, you can change it. Once it has answers, you have to avoid invalidating existing answers

Answer (score 2):

I flagged your question for migration to [Constructed Languages](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions).  That's a specialist forum that can help you with any kind of language invention query you might have!

Generally speaking, I'd recommend against deleting and starting over. The reason being, even though you think you "asked the wrong question", the question you asked is actually a valid question and may very well be useful to some person unknown to you a year or a decade into the future. I'd only recommend deletion if a question is e.g. blatantly racist or bigoted or irreligious in nature or seeks to incite violence or riot or is a call to harm a specific individual or group. Really horrible stuff. Also, if a question just doesn't make logical sense of any kind or is a "do my homework for me" kind of question then I might advise deletion as well.

But your question is perfectly fine as is, even though it's not the question you actually wanted to ask!  The good thing is: we don't place limits on the number of questions you can ask here!  Honestly, I'd suggest you join Constructed Languages and just ask your new question over there.  Alternatively, you could simply ask your new question here in Worldbuilding, and I'll flag it for migration to Constructed Languages! ;)

Comment: Migrating that specific question to Constructed Languages was counterproductive, in my opinion. The question was *not* about constructing a language: on the contrary, it was about *avoiding to construct* a language. That is, the question was seeking a relatively simple way to *fake* constructing a language sufficiently similar to Spanish so that (1) it would be recognized and more-or-less understood by people who can read Spanish and (2) it would be sufficiently not-Spanish.

Comment: @AlexP, probably my fault then, i did flag it for migration myself so that's on me.

Comment: @AlexP -- um, we do actually handle those kinds of questions as well, so no unprodutivity there.  In other words, we have resources available for folks engaged in all levels of language invention from yay I just finished translating the collected works of Shakespeare all the way down to umm...you do it for me!